# Apply Pivot on multiple colums and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

This is my sample table and I want to pivot the `Leave` column and get max to leave opening, debit and credit value and balance leaves

**Formula for Balance Leaves: leaveopen + leavecr - leaveused - leavedb**

[image]

Below is the expected output

[image]

so far I have managed to get leaveopening but not able to get all the values in a single query

```
select  e.Code,e.FName + ' ' + case when  e.LName !=null then  e.LName else ' ' end [Name],l.*
from .EmployeeDetail e
inner join (select * from(select Leave,LeaveOpen,EmployeeId,CompanyId from LeaveOpening where Leave in ('PL','SL','Coff') and employeeid=534 ) src  pivot(max(LeaveOpen) for Leave in (PL,SL,Coff)) as src2) l on e.Id = l.EmployeeId and e.CompanyId = l.CompanyId and employeeid=534
```

Comment: We'd love to help, but not do it all for you. Have an attempt and show us where you get stuck.

Comment: @DaleK please check updated question i had added query which i have tried

Comment: If you want us help you design the query, you'd better give us the table schema or data better than the table screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example using Case statement instead of Pivot.

```
select EmployeeId
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN Leave = 'PL' THEN LeaveOpen ELSE 0 END) AS [PL Opening]
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN Leave = 'PL' THEN LeaveCredit ELSE 0 END) AS [PL Credit]
  from LeaveOpening 
  group by EmployeeID
```